# Clinical Microbiology Books

Tags: microbiology, book-recommendation

I am looking for a good book about Clinical Microbiology, particularly good in Bacteriology and Bacteria Diagnosis (medium, plates, type of colonies...). With good photos. What are the bests in your opinion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Manual of Clinical Microbiology.

My version is old, but it is an excellent reference considered gold standard in the clinical science industry and by educators.   It has been used by clinical microbiologists for many years and is still coming out with updated revisions. It comes as a two volume set due to comprehensive content. Published by the American Society for Microbiology.

http://www.asmscience.org/content/book/10.1128/9781555817381